# Find top 20 values in descendent order of a big map

Tags: java

here's m code

```
Integer max = Collections.max(map.values());
int count = 20;
while(count>0)
{
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : map.entrySet())
        if(e.getValue() == max)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getKey() + "occurs" + e.getValue() + "times");
            count--;
        }
        max--;
}
```

This program runs in theta of n square time complexity. Is there a better way to display entries in the max which have top 20 maximum values in descending order?

Comment: Looks like you have a missing `}`.

Comment: Sort the values first.

Comment: Do you really need to care if you are talking about only 20 elements ?

Comment: @DavidHofmann It looks like he's checking the top 20, but the map itself is much bigger.

Comment: @DennisMeng yes the map is much bigger. I'm listing 20 entries in the map that have the top 20 values in descending order.

Comment: @JimGarrison I can't sort it when creating the map. By sort do you mean to create a new map with entries in descending order of values?

Comment: The map is as big a database. so it is not acceptable that I can do this in theta of n2 time. So please let me know how to go about this in a more efficient way

Comment: @PrasanaVenkatRamesh No need for a second map, you can use a sorted collection (like TreeSet or whatever)

Comment: And if you want the biggest 20, you can give a different comparator so that the TreeSet's iterator goes in reverse order.

Comment: Thankyou that solves this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efficient, O(n log 20), correct in all cases, and doesn't use anything outside the JDK:

```
PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> pq = 
  new PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>(
    20, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>() {
      @Override public int compare(
          Map.Entry<String, Integer> e1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> e2) {
        return e2.getValue().compareTo(e1.getValue());
        // not the other way around, since we want the maximum values
      }
    });
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
  pq.add(entry);
  if (pq.size() > 20) {
    pq.remove();
  }
}
while (!pq.isEmpty()) {
  Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry = pq.remove();
  System.out.println("Key: " + entry.getKey() + " Value: " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Extremely instructive reply. +1

Answer (score 3):

In general, I would do the simplest thing possible unless you have evidence that the performance is bad.  So, as a first go, I would simply sort the entire map, and then iterate through the first 20 elements, something like this:

```
Map<?,?> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<?,?>(map);
Iterator<Entry<?,?>> entries = mySortedMap.entrySet().iterator();
for (int i = 0; i<20; i++) {
  System.out.println(entries.next());
}
```

Don't prematurely optimize.  Now, if you *do* have a performance problem, then things get interesting.  I'll sketch the algorithm that I'd use.

1. Create an array of size 20
2. Iterate through the map in arbitrary order
3. If the next value of the map is in the top 20 seen so far, then do an insertion into the array at the appropriate location.

This algorithm has a much better worst and best case running time (theta(n)).

Comment: I can not use this as I'm looking at a map containing millions of entries. Creating a new map by copying millions of entries is ..... Not efficient

Comment: The second algorithm that I sketched does not require creating a second map.